Request for rich text area images from same salesforce org gives CORS error
I am trying to get the blob of the image from the image urls which are part of html content in Rich Text area field .i.e RTA images (eg url: <img src="https://instance-domain.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=a0VWB000000ZeVd&feoid=00N6g00000UQMTp&refid=0EMWB0000004wdJ">), I am trying to do this from the Javascript of aura component.
But unfortunately I am getting the CORS error when trying to get the blob.
JavaScript code looks like below:
async function getBase64ImageFromUrl(imageUrl) {
  var res = await fetch(imageUrl);
  var blob = await res.blob();
  
  console.log(blob);
}

getBase64ImageFromUrl('https://instance-domain.sandbox.file.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=a0VWB000000ZeVd&feoid=00N6g00000UQMTp&refid=0EMWB0000004wdJ')
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

Below error is thrown

Please note that my requirement is to get the blob of image from JavaScript and not use apex
Any help would be appreciated
